# Split data in column based on value of in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table full of Artist and Track Titles that is imported from two different places.

Some are correct with Artist and Title in different columns but then there are other rows where everything is in the Title column separated with '-' and the Artist column is `NULL`.

[image]

Changing it at the source is not an option because both data formats come in the same log file.

I think I need get all of the rows with a `NULL` value in the Artist column and then use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the Title column. My database is SQL server 2019.

I have tried a modifying a bunch of different examples on the internet but nothing comes close to working.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as a select query:

```
select t.*,
       (case when artist is null and title like '%-%'
             then left(title, charindex('-', title) - 1)
             else artist
        end) as imputed_artist,
       (case when artist is null and title like '%-%'
             then stuff(title, 1, charindex('-', title) + 1, '')
             else title
        end) as imputed_title
from t;
```

Similar logic can be applied in an `update`.

Comment: Thanks Gordan, that works really well, 
I just needed to change `then left(title, 1, charindex('-', title) - 1)` to `then left(title, charindex('-', title) - 1)` because of an error and  change ```then stuff(title, 1, charindex('-', title) + 2, '')` to `then stuff(title, 1, charindex('-', title) + 1, '')` because it chopped off the first character.

  Excuse my basicness but how would I change this to be an Update?

Comment: @no_event_logged . . . The first was a typo.  The second was a misunderstanding on how many spaces are around the hyphen.  I fixed the answer.